# Custom UUID generator in Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have class `Car`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="car", schema="my_schema")
@Builder // and some other annotations...
public class Car{

@NotNull
@Id
@Column(columnDefintion= "uuid", name="id", nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="CarGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
    name="CarGenerator",
    strategy = "com.myCars.utils.CarGenerator"
)
private UUID id;

}
```

and my `CarGenerator` class:

```
public class CarGenerator extends AbstarctUUIDGenerato{

    @Override
    public object generate(SharedSessionContractImplementator sharedSessionContractImplementator, Object o) throws HibernateException{
        if (o instance of Car car && car.getId() != null){
            return car.getId();
        }
        return UUID.randomUUID();   
    }   

}
```

My goal is to have *automated generating* of `id` in case I didn't assign some value manually.

For example in my test classes I create a car objects with builder like this:

```
Car car = Car.builder()
.brand("Toyota")
.model("Camry")
.builder();
carRepository.save(car);
//in this case I want Java to assign random UUID.

Car car = Car.builder()
.id(UUID.fromString("08f2364e-1fe3-4807-8378-09006f85e837"));
.brand("Toyota")
.model("Camry")
.builder();
carRepository.save(car);
//in this case I am the one who created id and I expect it will be saved like this to database.
```

I expect both cases to work properly.
How can be this behavior achieved? I was thinking about creating my own `CarBuilder` class. But I am curious if there is more elegant solution.

Comment: Is the `@Builder` annotation from Lombok, or something else?

Comment: What is lacking in the code you showed here?

Comment: @Mike Yes, Lombok.

Comment: @BasilBourque What do you mean?

Comment: You show code that appears to be the answer to your question. If so, why did you post there? If not, what about your shown code fails to meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and I was surprised I didn't find a documented solution for Hibernate 6, but I have finally came up with the solution that works. Hibernate comes with `org.hibernate.id.uuid.UuidGenerator`, but just extending it does not make it work. The `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.createGenerator()` will create your generator only if it's configured properly. What createGenerator does is it tries to get a constructor of your Generator class, but it must have the proper Annotation type. So you have to define your own annotation type for id generation and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of your generator. The problem here is that the annotations cannot be extended in Java, so I needed a little tweak to make the `super()` constructor of the `UuidGenerator` work. Here is my solution:

First, define your annotation class:

```java
@IdGeneratorType( CarIdGenerator.class )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD })
public @interface CarUuidGenerator {
    /**
     * Which style of generation should be used
     */
    UuidGenerator.Style style() default UuidGenerator.Style.TIME;

}
```

Now your `CarIdGenerator` class:

```java
public class CarIdGenerator extends UuidGenerator {

    public CarIdGenerator(
// You need your annotation instance here so that the AnnotationBinder can pick the right constructor
        CarUuidGenerator config,
        Member idMember,
        CustomIdGeneratorCreationContext creationContext
    ) {
// the superclass constructor won't take CarUuidGenerator as a parameter, and annotations cannot be extended, so we need to instantiate  UuidGenerator annotation manually:      
super(getUuidGeneratorAnnotation(config.style()), idMember, creationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) {
        if ((obj != null) && (obj instanceof Car)) {
            Car carEntity = (Car) obj;
            if (carEntity.getId() == null) {
                return (Serializable) super.generate(session, obj);
            }
            return carEntity.getId();
        }
        return (Serializable) super.generate(session, obj);
    }

    private static org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator getUuidGeneratorAnnotation(org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator.Style style) {
        return new org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Style style() {
                return style;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, you can annotate your `Car` entity class:

```java
public class Car {

@Id
@CarUuidGenerator
private UUID id;

}
```

Comment: It was way much easier in Hibernate 5 though

Answer (score 0):

Lombok's [@Builder annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) can be applied to a constructor, not just the class itself. So you can create a constructor that generates the ID, and apply the annotation to that like so:

```
public class Car {

@Builder
public Car(UUID id, String brand, String model) {
    this.id = id == null ? UUID.randomUUID() : id;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
}
```